# How to roll back mysql 5.6 to sql 5.1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, linux, mysql-5.1, centos

I recently updated mysql from 5.1 to 5.6 however it's causing too many issues with the websites hosted on my machine. Does anyone know how to remove mysql 5.6 and reinstall version 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to keep in mind first, you're not using features from 5.6, that are not available in 5.1 like  `utf8mb4` encoding (needed for emoji characters)

Take dump of all databases using `mysqldump` except `mysql`, is safer to recreate `mysql.user` table.

Try restoring on staging server first, to see if restored db works the way as you expect.

Comment: 1. I am not using any features from 5.6 that are not available in 5.1
2. I have backups of all my dbs on disc
3. Sadly I do not have the luxury of a staging env

I can tell you this though, I have successfully removed sql 5.6 and installed 5.1 but now I am having difficulty restoring the databases.

Comment: @de__bug What issue you are facing while doing restoration on `mysql 5.1`.